# libraries or database concatenation

Tags: python, database, concatenation, python-3.2

I am writing code that first reads in two .txt files into a program, and then later on I have to combine those two .txt files and perform multiple tasks with the resulting file.

As of now, I can read the files and assign them to variables, and I can print the two libraries separately, however I cannot figure out how to combine the files.

The code I have written so far looks like this:

```
def ReadAndMerge():
    library1=input("Enter 1st filename to read and merge:")
    library2=input("Enter 2nd filename to read and merge:")
    namelibrary1= open(library1, 'r')
    namelibrary2= open(library2, 'r')
    library1contents=namelibrary1.read()
    library2contents=namelibrary2.read()
    print(library1contents)
    print(library2contents)
    combinedlibraries=(library1, 'a')
    # ^ this didnt work, but it was what i have tried so far
    combinedlibraries.write(library2)
    print(combinedlibraries)
    return

ReadAndMerge()
```

I tried appending the library with another library, but Python did not seem to like what I was doing.

Library 1 looks like this:

```
Bud Abbott 51 92.3
Mary Boyd 52 91.4
Hillary Clinton 50 82.1
```

Library 2 looks like this:

```
Don Adams 51 90.4
Jill Carney 53 76.4
Randy Newman 50 41.2
```

Does anyone know a way of combining those two libraries?

so that when i print the combined libraries it will look like

```
Bud Abbott 51 92.3
Mary Boyd 52 91.4
Hillary Clinton 50 82.1
Don Adams 51 90.4
Jill Carney 53 76.4
Randy Newman 50 41.2
```

These are simple libraries - if someone could point me in the direction of a way to test bigger libraries with maybe over 50 names and combine the two libraries, that would be great.

Comment: Define "combine the libraries".

Comment: basically put the contents of library two at the bottom of library 1 so it becomes bud abbot mary boyd hillary clinton don adams jill carney randy newman

Comment: Do you understand how to open a file for writing and then writing a string to it? From the code sample you've presented us, I doesn't seem like you do (or at least you forgot to type the `open` function and `combinedlibraries` is just a tuple). I think that's your first step. After that it is trivial achieving what you want.

Comment: i have opened two files, the two files that i want to add together.  I dont understand how to actually combine the libraries.  I have library1 and library2 open but how do i put library1 and library2 together

Comment: This is not specifically addressing your issue, but I think one would benefit greatly in this type of application to use a simple flat-file database like SQLite or BerkeleyDB. Python has built-in support for both: `import sqlite3` or `import bdb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PedroRomano commented, it appears part of your issue is that you're missing a call to `open` in the line you say is not working. However, the later code still won't work quite right.

I also think that overwriting one of your starting data files is probably a bad idea. It makes you code no longer idempotent, so running it more than once will continue to have side effects.

Here's what I'd suggest instead:

```
def ReadAndMerge():
    library1filename = input("Enter 1st filename to read and merge:")
    with open(library1filename, 'r') as library1:
        library1contents = library1.read()

    library2filename = input("Enter 2nd filename to read and merge:")
    with open(library2, 'r') as library2:
        library2contents = namelibrary2.read()

    print(library1contents)
    print(library2contents)

    combined_contents = library1contents + library2contents  # concatenate text

    print(combined_contents)

    combined_filename = "combined.txt"    # ask user for name here?
    with open(combined_filename, "w") as combined_file:
        combined_file.write(combined_contents)
```

The `with` statements take care of closing the files once you're done with them (which is especially important when you're writing). Furthermore it uses a specific filename for the merged data, rather than adding to one of the source files.

One question you might want to consider though, is whether you actually need to write your combined data set to a file at all. If you're just going to reopen that file and read the data in again, you could skip the middle step and just use the combined data directly. You can replace the last three lines of the code above with `return combined_contents` if that's what you want.

Finally, a point mostly unrelated to your actual question: It's a bad idea to refer to your data as a "library". That word has a pretty specific meaning in Computer Programming (that is: software you load from outside of your project), and using it to refer to your data is confusing.

Comment: thank you blckknght, your comments and code was very helpful, what should i have referred to my data as though since libraries is an unacceptable term

Comment: @spenman: Hmm, I'm not sure there is a single obvious term. I guess "data" might be best. Or "data file" to specifically refer to the files themselves. Using libraries wasn't too confusing given the context.